# VS Code task to toggle the status bar on debug execution

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I prefer to hide the status bar in VS code but one nice feature is that it changes colour when your program is ready to debug. This is good when there is a lengthy build step as part of the `preLaunchTask`. I would like to unhide and hide the taskbar using `tasks.json`. The internal command is

```
workbench.statusBar.visible true
```

But I am not sure how I can execute this in a task by vscode

```
{
        "label": "debug with statusbar",
        "type": "process", // ?
        "group": "build",
        "args": [ true ],
        "command": "workbench.statusBar.visible",
        "dependsOn":["npm: build"]
},
{
     ...
```

It appears a custom task can either execute via shell or as a process. Is there a way to call vscode via one of these methods and execute the internal command? Or is there another way to achieve what I would like?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the settings file seems to do the trick since VS Code watches it in real time.

```
{
        "label": "debug with statusbar",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": "build",
        "args": [ 
            "-i", 
            "'/\"workbench.statusBar.visible\": false/s/.*/    \"workbench.statusBar.visible\": true/'",
            "/home/myuser/.config/Code/User/settings.json" 
        ],
        "command": "sed",
        "dependsOn":["npm: build"]
},
```

Then an equivalent task can be used for `postDebugTask`